# How to hide too long text in a twitter-bootstrap grid table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a bootstrap grid table which contains very long texts sometimes. Problem: if a text is too long then my table rows height changes as you can see in my example code. I want to hide the text instead.

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.zeile {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.row .col-xs-2 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}

.row .col-xs-5 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 zeile" id="too_long">
        Very long text Very long text Very long
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 zeile">
        short text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5L2w4yvr/

Comment: For overflow:hidden to work you have to specify some height. You could e.g. write a Javascript to check for the cell with the lowest height and then set this height to all the other cells.

Comment: I tried to set the height of `.zeile` to 5px but there is no difference.

Comment: If you could create a jsFiddle I could be able to help you more. P.S. You are invalidating Bootstrap grid by changing its default values with your CSS. I wouldn't suggest you do those things as Bootstrap already has table element.

Comment: there would be a huge white gap between the table rows otherwise, thats the reason i changed some attributes. JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/5L2w4yvr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look

```css
/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

.zeile {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.row {
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}

.row .col-xs-2 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}

.row .col-xs-5 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
}
.row {
table-layout: fixed; 
}
.row {
table-layout: fixed; 
}

.row .col-xs-2 {        
display: table-cell;
float: none;
width: 20%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 zeile" id="too_long">
        Very long text Very long text Very long
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-2 zeile">
        short text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-5 zeile">
        Text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Note:** I changed the layout from the one made out of divs to the table layout.

When you are using Bootstrap it's important that you never change its original css, at least not for the grid system itself as it will most likely result in problems later.

CSS:

```
td
{
    max-width: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Table grid:

```
<table class="table table-responsive">
  <tr>
    <td class="col-xs-3">
      Test Very long text Very long text Very long Very long text Very long text Very long
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">Test</td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">
      Test
    </td>
    <td class="col-xs-3">Test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Agramer/5L2w4yvr/2/)

Comment: This works for normal tables but not for twitter-bootstrap grid layout, but thank you

Comment: @EdwardBlack You got things wrong - check my layout in jsFiddle, it uses grid layout.

Comment: oh ok, im sorry.i mean that you are not using div's. +1 for your solution.

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:
 it works but it has fixed width: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/8m8dawyw/)

```
.row .col-xs-2 {
   display:table-cell;
   float:none;
max-width: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Solution 2: it works without fixed width : [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/silviagreen/k19tg5nr/)

```
.zeile {
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow:hidden;
}


.row {
   margin-left: 0px;
   margin-right: 0px;
   display:table;
   width:100%;

 }

 .row .col-xs-2 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;


  max-width: 100px;
overflow: hidden;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;


}

.row .col-xs-5 {
  display:table-cell;
  float:none;
 }

 .col-xs-5 , .col-xs-2 {
  max-width: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
  .col-xs-2 {
    width: 30%;
  }
  .col-xs-5  {
    width: 70%;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
.row {
table-layout: fixed; 
}

.row .col-xs-2 {        
display: table-cell;
float: none;
width: 20%;
text-overflow: ellipsis;
white-space: nowrap;
}
```